# How to write dynamic sql query to pull data from database when query criteria is stored in other table

Tags: sql

I have a UI from where user can enter some selection query which is being stored in one table called `T`. I have to use the table `T` to pull data from data model which satisfies selection criteria stored in it.

Eg of selection criteria

```
dept_desc LIKE '%18 ALBUMS STAMPS & CARD%' 
AND class_desc LIKE '%081 RUBBER STAMPS%' 
AND item_type_desc LIKE '%Seasonal%'
```

Comment: Your question seems to be incomplete: what DBMS are you using? What have you done yourself already to try and solve this, can you show us a query or some code?

Comment: Does the table store the entire selection string `dept_desc LIKE '%18 ALBUMS STAMPS & CARD%' AND class_desc LIKE '%081 RUBBER STAMPS%' AND item_type_desc LIKE '%Seasonal%'` in one field, or is each selection condition stored in a separate field - eg. does dept_desc hold a string `'%18 ALBUMS STAMPS & CARD%'`?

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't sound like a very good design to me.

The only real way to do it would be to dynamically create the SQL from the user input (which would be dangerous and really suck).

I'd recommend you revise your UI such that it programmatically selects out the columns and values to search within into distinct variables (or arrays of variables) then store that in a proper table structure.  From there you should be able to use more traditional static queries joining to the data you collected.